# unable to install Google's Droid Sans Mono font

Tags: macos, install, font

I've downloaded Droid Sans, Droid Serif, and Droid Sans Mono fonts from google.com/fonts and the first two have installed just fine.

OS X 10.9.5. I'm extracting the font file from the download ZIP file, double-clicking the TTF file, then clicking "Install".

Unfortunately, I can't get Droid Sans Mono to install; it looks like some message boxes pop up very quickly, but I can't read what they say. When I validate the font file, it looks okay, but installation doesn't do anything.

Using the Console app, the following messages appeared during the time I try to install the font:

```
4/20/15 1:36:22.068 PM taskgated[19]: binary have embedded signature that validated /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuickLookUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/QuickLookUIHelper.app[24856]
4/20/15 1:36:22.105 PM QuickLookUIHelper[24856]: LSExceptions [0x7fe5f0707e30] loaded
4/20/15 1:36:22.112 PM Finder[1250]: LSExceptions [0x6180002b4640] loaded
4/20/15 1:36:22.125 PM lsboxd[1281]: Connection from pid 24856
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: OK - I've already upvoted this and now have edited the details in the post. Seems odd you don't get any message. Is there anything in the console app at the time when you click the font file? Select Show Log List in the header and then All Messages on the left under the Show/Hide icon.

Comment: Updated the post to include the log messages I see during the timeframe where I try to import the font.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install it from [fontsquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/droid-sans-mono) on my mac osx version 10.13.3. Try it out